FFmpeg reports an error: No space left on device, when there is enough space
I need to use FFmpeg to process a large number of audio files (83,503 in opus format), actually, to cut a large number of audio segments (17,894,974 in total, 1 second or a few seconds in opus format) from each audio file, and save them to hard disk (My work is related to deep learning. This is a preprocessing of the WenetSpeech dataset.)  I code a Python script, using multiple processes to call FFmpeg for processing, the specific call command is:
ffmpeg -loglevel warning -y -i input_file.opus -ss beginTime1 -to endTime1 -c copy output_file1.opus -ss beginTime2 -to endTime2 -c copy output_file2.opus -ss beginTime3 -to endTime3 -c copy output_file3.opus

Now, the problem is that ffmpeg will report errors when the program has been running for a while
2024-08-30 02:07:53,895 - app - ERROR - preprocess_turbo.py:112 - ffmpeg stderr: b'/host_ssd1/mooki/Datasets/WenetSpeech_20240829/train/podcast-B00114_X0000029224_149462528_130.85-132.4_46.opus: No space left on device\n’

I can guarantee that I have enough space on my hard drive, what is this and how can I solve it?
Additional information is as follows:

I run the program in the Docker container, and no resource limit option was set in the container startup command. The output of the ulimit -a command is as follows:
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 6185466
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1048576
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) unlimited
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited


Each input audio may be divided into many segments (up to 4000 segments), so there may have many -ss beginTime-to endTime -c copy output_file.opus groups in one FFmpeg command, because the input and output paths are absolute paths, which are very long. So I initially suspected that there might be a risk of the command being too long to exceed the system limit, but I has used getconf ARG_MAX to see that the command length limit is 2621440, which is large enough, there should be no risk, and no related errors are reported.
At present, I doubt whether FFmpeg wrote temporary files to a temporary path (such as /tmp) during the execution and did not delete them in time after the command exited, resulting in insufficient space after the execution of the program. However, I can guarantee that the remaining space of /tmp is sufficient. I also tried to adjust the number of processes to 1, but after running for a few hours, the error was still reported: No space left on device.

I don't know what the problem is, could you please tell me how to solve it, or how to further locate the problem?

Update 1: Here is the output of df -h:
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay         3.6T  1.1T  2.5T  31% /
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs           756G     0  756G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
shm              16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/nvme0n1    3.6T  1.1T  2.5T  31% /workspace
/dev/sda8       381G   69M  381G   1% /host_smallhome
overlay         3.6T  1.1T  2.5T  31% /host_home/docker/lib/overlay2/0708b1316a5cc751ad81fdfda1bd1de8c9f3d357476bb6c305ba484329e856c1/merged
overlay         3.6T  1.1T  2.5T  31% /host_home/docker/lib/overlay2/8d8cae33df82b48957fce3b64bfa04043a67958c6b8496195169c47b24aaa507/merged
overlay         3.6T  1.1T  2.5T  31% /host_home/docker/lib/overlay2/41d5caa747fa251e7b656c8550ed2310aaee7956274ce1c7fe6ded55ae890429/merged
/dev/nvme1n1    3.6T  1.3T  2.4T  34% /host_ssd1
tmpfs           756G   12K  756G   1% /proc/driver/nvidia
/dev/sda2        19G  4.6G   13G  27% /usr/bin/nvidia-smi
tmpfs           756G  877M  755G   1% /run/nvidia-fabricmanager/socket
devtmpfs        756G     0  756G   0% /dev/nvidia0
overlay         3.6T  1.1T  2.5T  31% /host_home/docker/lib/overlay2/ae7e1f603c705c5adea354d0e34acc1cc4ccadb946b07354b828cbb88be8a48b/merged


Update 2: I changed the code, specifically, when doing audio segmentation, the new version of the code will skip the corresponding processing if there is already a file in the target path. Then I tried to run the new code several times, and found that the number of files stopped growing when it reached 10031064 (approximate num, I counted it by tree | wc-l), it seems that I encountered some kind of limit, but I checked the df -ih, there is still a lot of margin, why?
The output of df -ih is:
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
overlay          233M  2.0M  231M    1% /
tmpfs            189M   716  189M    1% /dev
tmpfs            189M    17  189M    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
shm              189M     1  189M    1% /dev/shm
/dev/nvme0n1     233M  2.0M  231M    1% /workspace
/dev/sda8         25M    12   25M    1% /host_smallhome
overlay          233M  2.0M  231M    1% /host_home/docker/lib/overlay2/0708b1316a5cc751ad81fdfda1bd1de8c9f3d357476bb6c305ba484329e856c1/merged
overlay          233M  2.0M  231M    1% /host_home/docker/lib/overlay2/8d8cae33df82b48957fce3b64bfa04043a67958c6b8496195169c47b24aaa507/merged
overlay          233M  2.0M  231M    1% /host_home/docker/lib/overlay2/41d5caa747fa251e7b656c8550ed2310aaee7956274ce1c7fe6ded55ae890429/merged
/dev/nvme1n1     233M   20M  214M    9% /host_ssd1
tmpfs            189M    13  189M    1% /proc/driver/nvidia
/dev/sda2        1.2M   61K  1.2M    6% /usr/bin/nvidia-smi
tmpfs            189M  2.0K  189M    1% /run/nvidia-fabricmanager/socket
devtmpfs         189M  1.3K  189M    1% /dev/nvidia0
overlay          233M  2.0M  231M    1% /host_home/docker/lib/overlay2/ae7e1f603c705c5adea354d0e34acc1cc4ccadb946b07354b828cbb88be8a48b/merged


Update 3: Following the link @Tom Yan commented, I execute tune2fs -l /dev/nvme1n1. It seems that the num of Free inodes is big enough. I also tried to create several new files using touch manually and succeeded. It's weired.
The output of tune2fs -l /dev/nvme1n1 is:
tune2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Filesystem volume name:   <none>                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Last mounted on:          /ssd1                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Filesystem UUID:          3259a3dc-3cee-46b1-813d-80712ba03d3e                                                                                                                                                                                      
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)                                                                                                                                                                                                               
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent 64bit flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize quota project                                                  
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Filesystem state:         clean                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Errors behavior:          Continue                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Filesystem OS type:       Linux                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Inode count:              244195328                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Block count:              976754646                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Reserved block count:     0                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Free blocks:              961137861                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Free inodes:              244195316                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
First block:              0                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Block size:               4096                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Fragment size:            4096                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Group descriptor size:    64                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Reserved GDT blocks:      1024                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Blocks per group:         32768                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Fragments per group:      32768 
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Thu Jul 18 05:51:38 2024
Last mount time:          Thu Jul 18 05:52:24 2024
Last write time:          Thu Jul 18 05:52:24 2024
Mount count:              1
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Thu Jul 18 05:51:38 2024
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          1036 MB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:               256
Required extra isize:     32
Desired extra isize:      32
Journal inode:            8
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      0361721b-e492-4277-8b00-4c23819de4ae
Journal backup:           inode blocks
User quota inode:         3
Group quota inode:        4
Project quota inode:      12


Could be the same question as https://serverfault.com/q/396768

Here. Ext4: "Maximum number of files per directory: 10 million approximately (can be extended with large_dir feature)". Relevant?

Thanks @KamilMaciorowski, problem solved. As with the link above, the reason for the problem is that when the number of files in a single folder exceeds 10 million (9.9 million in my case), the file system performance deteriorates significantly, and I reorganize the output folder so that the "No space left on device" error does not appear.
